# Bounceback management Exchange 2010

Tags: exchange-2010

We are currently migrating to Exchange 2010 and wanted to know if there was any better management of bouncebacks.

Our company has a database that has marketing sent to it, and while some users are better than others, we end up with a heck of a lot of emails that bounce that don't get actioned (i.e. the email address updating or recipient deleting)

What is the most sensible way of handling bounce-backs with Exchange 2010 on a semi-automated basis?

Answer (score 0):

Why not use a proper list management system like phplist that does the bounce handling for you?

http://docs.phplist.com/PhpListConfigBounces.html

Or even a commercial system like MailChimp etc?

Comment: This is what I was basically asking - has Exchange 2010 added anything that helps managing bouncebacks or is it still sensible to fall back on other products?

Comment: Email server != List Manager. If you want bounceback management, use a list management program. Exchange itself isn't aware of the lists, is it? So you want to use something that is...